# PlayFramework Build.scala "expected class or object definition"

Tags: playframework

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaTodoList) and I added:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "8.4-702.jdbc4"
)
```

And got this error:

```
/home/alpha/PLAY/CivCraftHelper/project/Build.scala:1 expected class or object definition
    val appDependencies = Seq(
    ^
    one error found
```

I'm using type-Safe activator and --version returns

```
sbt launcher version 0.13.0
```

I'm rather new to the framework and I have no idea what is causing this.
If there is any information I need to add to the post, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may be on play 2.2 from your sbt version, but the link you have shown is a 2.1 tutorial. In the [2.2 tutorial](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTodoList) you would be adding

```
libraryDependencies += "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "8.4-702.jdbc4"
```

to the `build.sbt` file rather. Could you give that a try?

Comment: I had to add it to the existing libraryDependencies, but it compiles! Thanks